# Search for custom table view cell does not work and returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uisearchbar

I have a UIViewController which acts as a TableViewController and on top of that is the search bar. Searching in the search bar should filter the results in the array which it is doing although I have a custom cell which I want to use but its returning null.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    struct Cake {
        var name = String()
        var type = String()
    }

    var cakes = [Cake(name: "avocado", type: "fruit"),
             Cake(name: "blueberry", type: "fruit"),
             Cake(name: "swerve", type: "sweetener")]

    var isSearching = false

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    var filteredCakes = [Cake]()

    //var filteredFoodIDescArray = [String]()
    //var filteredFoodImgArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        filteredCakes = cakes
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        self.tableView.register(ViewControllerTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.filteredCakes.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {
        //let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        var cell = self.tableView!.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        //cell.foodItemTitle.text = self.filteredCakes[indexPath.row].name

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.filteredCakes[indexPath.row].name
        //cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.filteredCakes[indexPath.row].size

        return cell
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        // If we haven't typed anything into the search bar then do not filter the results
        if searchController.searchBar.text! == "" {
            filteredCakes = cakes
        } else {
            // Filter the results
            filteredCakes = cakes.filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) }
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Get a compile error where it says: Value of UIType 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'foodItemTitle' on this line: `cell.foodItemTitle.text = self.filteredCakes[indexPath.row].name`

```
class ViewControllerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var foodItemTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var foodItemDesc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var foodItemImg: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

It returns `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on `cell.foodItemTitle.text = self.filteredCakes[indexPath.row].name`. If I use a UITableViewCell instead of Custom cell it works but otherwise not.

How can I declare my custom cell in such a way that I can actually assign the text labels from `ViewControllerTableViewCell`?

Comment: Is the `foodItemTitle` label connected to the storyboard? If it's connected correctly, the circle to its left should be filled in.

Comment: Also make sure `filteredCakes ` holding any values

Comment: @nathan yes, its located inside ViewController

Comment: @fscore but is it connected in the storyboard? If the connection got deleted, it will cause the issue you are having. Double-check that the little circle to the left of the `@IBOutlet` is filled in.

Comment: @nathan yes I just checked it is connected in the storyboard

Comment: @nathan It gives me a compile error to give do this `cell.foodItemTitle.text = self.filteredCakes[indexPath.row].name`

Comment: In your storyboard, did you set `Identifier` to "cell"?

Comment: @fscore that line of code is giving a compile time error or a run time error? What does the error message say?

Comment: if `ViewControllerTableViewCell` is in your storyboard (within the same controller) then you don't have to call `self.tableView.register`. Just need to set the `Reuse Identifier` of the cell `"Cell"` in storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you work with Prototype cell then there is no need to register the cell with `tableView`, it will automatically register for that `tableView`. So simply remove that `register` code from `viewDidLoad` and you all set to go.

**Remove this line:**

```
self.tableView.register(ViewControllerTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Answer (score 0):

You firstly need to get `nib` of your `ViewControllerTableViewCell`

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "YOUR_CUSTOM_CELL_NIB_NAME", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "YOUR_CUSTOM_CELL_ID")
```

Comment: This is not necessary when using storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

The only place you can force unwrap is this line of code `cell.foodItemTitle.text`. You are declaring your `foodItemTitle` as `UILabel!`.

Make sure you set the custom class name to your custom cell on storyboard, and then connected them correctly like this

[image]